# automation of command in shell script

Tags: shell, ksh

Hi I am automating some comands . There is a way of calling perl program which can be called by going to particular user. I have written code as

```
expect -c 'spawn su - poletst; send "1\r";interact'
cmsyscon Test
```

This script has to run on server. After Selecting user the area is selected. cmsyscon is a command wich calls a  perl module(i don't know much). The problem is that user is switched and area is selected but hten nothing happen on console and when i give exit command on console then cmsyscon runs. what's the problem with the script and how to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried expect before but from the looks of it, expect spawns a process which your exit command kills allowing cmsyscon to run. I.e. You're not executing the cmsyscon within the process you just spawned.

Try something like:

```
expect -c 'spawn su - poletst; send "1\r"; interact; cmsyscon Test'
```

Answer (score 0):

Send your command manually to the switched user's shell:

```
expect -c 'spawn su - poletst; send "1\r"; send "cmsyscon Test\r";interact'
```

Or

```
expect -c 'spawn su - poletst; send "1\r"; expect "\$"; send "cmsyscon Test\r";interact'
```

Replace `\$` with some parts of your user's prompt if it doesn't work.